# Can ctypes export symbols from Python to a shared object?

Tags: python, shared-libraries, ctypes

I'm trying to use the ctypes module to unit test C code using Python unit test frameworks. I use GCC and Linux. The C file under test (packet.c) has a header file (packet.h) like this:

```
#ifndef PACKET_H
#define PACKET_H

void byte_received(char b);
void packet_received_callback(int length, char *packet);

#endif
```

The idea is that a main function calls `byte_received` multiple times with some bytes, and when a valid packet with a valid checksum was found then `packet_received_callback` is called back. The `packet_received_callback` function is not defined in packet.c, but should be supplied by the caller code (eg. main.c or a Python module).

If I compile packet.c, make a shared object from it, and load it from python using `ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("./packet.so")` then I get an OSError with message "undefined symbol". This is expected of course because I do not provide `packet_received_callback` anywhere. And this is what I don't know how to do.

**My question is: can I somehow get ctypes to export a global function by that name when loading the shared object?** I know how to do that in a C executable, but not from Python and ctypes. The ctypes module supports C calling Python (by passing a function pointer as an argument to a C function), which suggest that what I want is at least theoretically possible.

*I already know that I can work around this by changing the C code so that `byte_received` call a function pointer stored in a global variable instead of a global function (and that's my backup plan). I'm asking this question because I want to avoid that.*

Comment: Use your backup plan.  The C linker needs a function and Python can't provide it.  You have to pass the Python function (wrapped in ctypes) at runtime.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: "[...] and Python can't provide it" Can you explain why?

Comment: Python functions need a Python interpreter to execute their byte code. They are not in a form a C linker can consume.

Comment: The point of ctypes.CFUNCTYPE() is to turn a Python function into a form that a C program can use.

Comment: My question is: can Python give the linker such a function to resolve the symbol dependencies?

Comment: No. You need the runtime ctypes wrapper.

Comment: If you are interested, could you explain how you reached that conclusion? I asked my question to get technical insights. Opinions do not help me achieve that goal.

Comment: A C linker needs code in a format such as COFF or ELF.  Python byte code is not either of them and needs a Python interpreter to run it.  I haven't looked at the ctypes implementation, but to call Python from C requires using the Python C API (and its interpreter).  I *have* written [SWIG](http://www.swig.org) wrappers that can call Python from C, so I do know the mechanics needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although `ctypes` does not support this use case, it turns out the newer `cffi` library does: https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#extern-python-new-style-callbacks